# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'SFType' objects (simple-salesforce)

Tags: python, salesforce, simple-salesforce

my project is to extract the contents of all my salesforce tables, including the custom ones. To do this, I need to know the names of the columns (fields), since SOQL does not support "SELECT * from TABLENAME".

With simple-salesforce, I know that the following works:

```
sf = Salesforce(username='foo@bar.com', password='abcd', security_token='ZCdsdPdE4eI2DZMl5gwCFIGEFU')

    field_data = sf.Contact.describe()["fields"]
```

But my problem is that I need to parameterize the "Contact" string in the actual method call above, so that I can call this method for objects that I do not know the names of (ie not defined in standard salesforce). For example I need to do:

```
    field_data = sf.CustomTableName.describe()["fields"]
```

When I try and use the SFType class:

```
contact = SFType('Contact',sf.sessionid,sf.sf_instance)
f = contact.describe()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./simple-example.py", line 13, in <module>
    f = contact.describe()["fields"]
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/simple_salesforce/api.py", line 430, in describe
    result = self._call_salesforce('GET', self.base_url + 'describe')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/simple_salesforce/api.py", line 570, in _call_salesforce
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.session_id,
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'SFType' objects
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 4):

If you look in the [source code for simple-salesforce](https://github.com/heroku/simple-salesforce/blob/44dab67c59ee7c82aff9d3844a269184d7ca0d30/simple_salesforce/api.py#L77) (as of 2015-11-12) you'll see that in the `init()` of `Salesforce()` we set the session to `self.session_id` and instance to `self.sf_instance`

In your case, you're using `sf.sessionid`, and because simple-salesforce is setup to return a `SFType()` object whenever a method or property does not exist on `Salesforce()` (and `sessionid` does not exist on `Salesforce()`) you're actually inserting a `SFType()` object into the init of your `SFType()`

`SFType.__init__()` doesn't do any form of validation to confirm you're passing in strings as arguments, so the error you're getting is from simple-salesforce trying to use the `SFType()` object you're passing in as a string.

Try this code:

```py
contact = SFType('Contact', sf.session_id, sf.sf_instance)
f = contact.describe()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and seemed to have fixed this by removing the protocol ("https://") from the instance_url. This is weird but seems to work for me now and I can do `contact.describe()`

Something like this:

```
contact = SFType(sf_object, session_id, instance_url.replace("https://",''))
contact.describe()
```